# jquery mobile selectbox hides fixed toolbars

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I have strange problem with native selectbox on Android devices - in the case of longer page like screen height and after click on selectbox - fixed toolbars hide.
Part of the code (original has approx. 7 selectboxes):

```
<div data-role="page" id="profile" class="whole_page">
    <div data-role="header" data-tap-toggle="false" data-position="fixed">
        <img src="img/logo.png" class="ui-btn-left header_image" /><h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
           <label for="occupation">Povolanie:</label>
       <select class="selecttmenu" name="occupation" id="occupation" data-theme="a" onchange="check_profile_form()">
               <option value="0" data-placeholder="true"></option>
               <option value="1">student</option>
               <option value="2">employed</option>
               <option value="3">unemployed</option>
            </select> 
        </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false" class="footer_border" data-id="myfooter">
        <div data-role="navbar" class="navbarik">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-theme="c" class="profile ui-btn-active ui-state-persist active-white"><img src="img/profile.png" class="footer_image" /><br /><span class="footer_text">profile</span></a></li>
                <li class="last"><a href="#" data-theme="c" class="logout inactive-white"><img src="img/logout.png" class="footer_image" /><br /><span class="footer_text">logout</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every answer will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.